# Are there any special characters in Windmill? How do I override?

Tags: windmill, testautomationfx

I'm attempting to closeout a popup named [Close].

```
client.click(link=u'[Close]')
client.waits.forElement(link=u'[Close]', timeout=u'8000')
```

It seems to die here.

```
'debug': u'Looking up id docname, failed.

>>> test_results: ERROR    Test Failure in test {'version': u'0.1', u'suite_name
': u'exampletest', 'result': False, 'starttime': u'2012-3-6T11:56:0.877Z', 'outp
ut': None, 'debug': u'Looking up id docname, failed.', u'params': {u'uuid': u'44
d8908f-8009-11e1-9665-2c27d7ea08c4', u'id': u'docname'}, 'endtime': u'2012-3-6T1
1:56:0.877Z', u'method': u'asserts.assertNode'}
```

Is there a way to include literal brackets in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the link had a space between the brackets and letters.

```
[ Close ]
```

not

```
[Close]
```